# How to use the Create Case action from the Human Resources: Core Spoke in Flow Designer

Tags: servicenow, servicenow-hrsd

I'm trying to create a new HR Case in the flow designer when I saw this "Create Case" action. It has 3 inputs: Case Table Name, Case Values Record, and Caee Fields. I have no idea what Case Values Record is. And the spoke is not documented anywhere. I'm currently using the Record Producer action, but it seems that it's not intended for HR Cases (Description is not auto-filled by variables when created). Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Ok, found it in the out-of-the-box Flow "Case Trigger Custom Condition"!

[image]